# How do you manipulate Insertion Sort to always run in the worst case complexity

Tags: time-complexity, hashcode, pseudocode, insertion-sort

I have to implement a hash function that takes an array and a index as the arguments and returns
an integer. I then have to use this hash function to cause Insertion Sort to always run in the worst case complexity even if the resulting array does not end up getting sorted.

Pseudocode below:

```
function INSERTIONSORT(A[0..n − 1])
for i ← 1 to n − 1 do
     j ← i − 1
     while j ≥ 0 and HASH(A, j + 1) < HASH(A, j) do
          SWAP(A[j + 1], A[j])
          j ← j − 1
```

I know that the worst case complexity of insertion sort is O(n<sup>2</sup>), but if I made `HASH(A, j + 1)` return an integer which is always less than `HASH(A, j)` so that the while loop runs for its maximum amount of loops, would that achieve O(n<sup>2</sup>) time complexity?

Comment: Why not just make `HASH(A, j) = -j`? This would make the comparison into `-(j+1) < -j` which is always true, so the algorithm would always swap.

Comment: @kaya3 The OP wants to "implement a hash function", not to modify the algorithm.

Comment: @horcrux Uh, yeah, so the OP gets to decide what the hash function does. Something like `function HASH(A, j): return -j` would be implementing a hash function with the desired property.

Comment: @kaya3 Sorry, I misunderstood your comment. I thought you were suggesting to replace `HASH(A, j)` with `-j` in the algorithm. Looking back, it wouldn't make sense :-)

Comment: @horcrux No worries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the last question "would that achieve O(n<sup>2</sup>) time complexity?" itself is wrong.
It obviously achieve O(n<sup>2</sup>) time complexity, how couldn't it?

If you want to work **always** in the worst-case scenario, besides O(n<sup>2</sup>) you basically want also to ensure o(n<sup>2</sup>), i.e. you want to fix a lower bound which is equal to the upper bound.

Anyway, the answer is still yes: mading `HASH(A, j + 1)` returning an integer which is always less than `HASH(A, j)`, you ensure that the inner loop always runs `i` times. So for any execution you will do **exactly** 1+...+(n-1), which is quadratically (both lower and upper) bounded.